# Google map info window blocking click events

Tags: android, google-maps

I have implemented a [InfoWindowAdapter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter#getInfoContents%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker%29) that returns this inflated XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layoutRoot"
    android:clickable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/snippetText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Which is inflated by

```
public class MarkerWindowProvider implements InfoWindowAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater lInflater;
    private InfoWindowClickListener onClick;
    
    public MarkerWindowProvider(Context parent, InfoWindowClickListener onClick) {
        lInflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.onClick = onClick;
    }
    
    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {
        View contents = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_infowindow, null);
        ((TextView)contents.findViewById(R.id.titleText)).setText(marker.getTitle());
        ((TextView)contents.findViewById(R.id.snippetText)).setText(marker.getTitle());
        contents.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick.onClick(marker);
            }
        });
        return contents;
    }
    
    public interface InfoWindowClickListener {
        public void onClick(Marker marker);
    }
}
```

The inflated layout is displayed instead of the stock info window but the OnClick method never fires regardless of which method i choose to inflate the XML into.

I really need this functionality. Any ideas on why this is not working? Any alternatives?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's said, that you can NOT handle any events from views inside your info window. This popup is not a "live" view, you even can't disable default background selector (to block blinking). Unfortunately. 
So it's not recommended to put buttons and text views for input.